# Send message from JavaScript to Java in BlackBerry application

Tags: javascript, blackberry

What are the various options for sending messages using JavaScript from a web page embedded in a BlackBerry application into the application itself.

In Android, I can use `addJavascriptInterface` to create a first-class DOM object for communicating up directly. And in iOS, I can use the page `location.href` to ferry messages up indirectly. I'm just not familiar with BB to know how to plan this out.

Nothing at this point is written. So all options are available. Any tips or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for could probably be accomplished with one or both of [`BrowserField.extendScriptEngine()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html#extendScriptEngine%28java.lang.String,%20net.rim.device.api.script.Scriptable%29) or [`BrowserField.executeScript()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html#executeScript%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Cool. Thank you. I was hoping the solution would work like this. extendScriptEngine() is just what I'll need.